# Fluid TYPO3: Get flux variables from other page

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-10.x

I try to display a value from a subpage on my main page. This what I defined in the subpage:

```
        <flux:field.select
                name="ampel"
                label="Ampel"
                items="{
                       0:{0:'Rot',1:'rot'},
                       1:{0:'Gelb',1:'gelb'},
                       2:{0:'Grün',1:'grun'}
                       }"
        />
```

I need to get the value of {ampel} on the main page in an other fluid-component.
I tried this solution:
[Fluid Typo3 - How to get variables definded via flux from different page uids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31555978/fluid-typo3-how-to-get-variables-definded-via-flux-from-different-page-uids)
but the field `tx_fed_page_flexform` is empty. I think they changed the storage in the newer TYPO3 versions. I also can't find the values in the database. Shouldn't they be in the `tt_content` table?

I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: Did you checked this? See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39370129/5961782. Yes, you might need customization

Comment: Flux content ist written in "tt_content/pi_flexform" You cant access them. You can do this with TCA and adding a new column to tt_content table.